# How do you print rows and columns in a 2-d array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get this array to display 4 values arranged in a 2x2 array. With what I'm doing so far, I'm getting an array out of bounds error. How can I do this display properly?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;



 public class GridPractice
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  //declarations
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  Random  generator = new Random();
  int [][] grid;    //un-instantiated grid
  int size = 0; //number of rows and columns

  //get size of grid - no validation & instantiate
  System.out.print("Enter size of grid: ");
  size = in.nextInt();
  grid = new int[size][size];

   //fill grid with random number from 1..99
  System.out.println();
  for (int row=0; row<size; row++)
  {
     for (int col=0; col<size; col++)
     {
        grid[row][col] = generator.nextInt(100); //random numbers 0.99 - not 100

     }

   }

  System.out.printf("%2d\n", grid[size][size]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        System.out.printf("%2d ", grid[row][col]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: So all I needed to do was use the line System.out.println();
Why though?

Comment: It outputs a newline character. You only want a newline character at the end of each grid row, not between each value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            System.out.print(grid[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

plus remove this line, this is the culprit of the exception:

```
System.out.printf("%2d\n", grid[size][size]);
```